# I have scanned qrcode using React. It shows the result. My code is OK. But I want to save the result in a variable. How can I do it using react?

Tags: reactjs, scanning

I have scanned qrcode using React. It shows the result. My code is OK. But I want to save the result in a variable. How can I do it using react?
Below is my code. I want to save the result(that is received after scanning qrcode) in a variable.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import QrReader from 'react-qr-scanner'
 
class App extends Component {
  
  constructor(props){
    
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      delay: 100,
      result: 'No result',
    }
 
    this.handleScan = this.handleScan.bind(this)
  }
  handleScan(data){
    let value= this.setState({
      result: data,
    })
    console.log(value);
  }
  handleError(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
  render(){
    const previewStyle = {
      height: 240,
      width: 320,
    }
 
    return(
      <div>
        <QrReader
          delay={this.state.delay}
          style={previewStyle}
          onError={this.handleError}
          onScan={this.handleScan}
          />
        <p>{this.state.result}</p>`enter code here`
        
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have a variable. this.state.result is holding your data after you successfully scan. If you wanted to make a copy of it for some reason you could say

```
let value = [...this.state.result]
```

I'm not sure what value would actually look like or what you would need this for but that's one way to save that value into a new variable.

Answer (score 0):

Your handlescan should be

```
handleScan(data){

    this.setState({
      result: data,
    })
    console.log(data);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks  for the answer. I put the result in the variable 'value'. I got the result in the console if I log 'value'. The result is {StudyId: 1, CageId:1}. I need CageId. To print CageId, I did value.CageId or this.state.result.CageId. But it is showing cannot read the property 'CageId' of null. Please let me know how to print 'CageId'?

Answer (score 0):

The `handleScan(data)` function has to look like this:

```
handleScan(data){
    let value = data
    this.setState({ result: data })
    console.log(value)
}
```

Let me go through what this is doing.

1. Save the value of the variable `data` in the variable `value`
2. Save the value of the variable `data` in the state object
3. Print out the value saved in varaible `value`

Alternatively just use the state to save and print the value.

```
handleScan(data){
    this.setState({ result: data })
    console.log(this.state.result)
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. I put the result in the variable 'value'. I got the result in the console if I log 'value'. The result is {StudyId: 1, CageId:1}. I need CageId. To print CageId, I did value.CageId or this.state.result.CageId. But it is showing cannot read the property 'CageId' of null. Please let me know how to print 'CageId'?

Comment: can you please create a codesandbox sample, so it is easier to debug?. remember this.setState is asynchronous

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-almeida-lxtg7?file=/src/App.js